# SSH local to SSH remote server through Windows RDP jump point

Tags: windows, ssh, putty

Is possible make tunnel for linux (ssh) through windows (rdp) to linux (ssh)? Just make ssh tunnel on windows. Is possible with putty for example?

**Problem** is that now I must go from local linux to windows jump point with RDP, and then from this windows jump point I can connect to linux remote server via ssh (putty).

Is some way to setup something on windows JP (for example in putty) to connect from local (SSH) to remote server (SSH) "directly"? Or ssh server on windows JP is needed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I very much doubt you'll be able to do this over RDP as putty doesn't understand the the RDP protocol, but with Windows 10 you can enable a native SSH server. With this enabled you should be able to use the Windows machine as a bastion host.

Docs for setting up OpenSSH server for Windows can be found on the Microsoft website [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse)

Comment: Ok, and for w7?

Comment: Windows 7 goes End of Life January 14th 2020, upgrade to Windows 10 before then.

Comment: This is the problem, I don't have permissions to do that. :/ And if I can ping linux server from my host after vpn connection? How is it impossible to connect via port 22? I tried `telnet IP 80`, it works. No `ufw` or `iptables` on server.

Comment: Those are totally separate questions to the one you asked.